# Movie where piano player gets robotic hands

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to identify a live-action movie from the 80s or 90s, but I don't have much to go on. It only barely fits into the sci-fi genre, but is probably classified as drama. Here's what I remember:

- A young man (high school age, maybe?) is a promising piano player but has both hands cut off in a vicious attack, perhaps a home invasion.
- Afterwards, the protagonist is severely depressed, even after he ends up getting experimental robotic prosthetic hands that resemble robot gauntlets.
- The protagonist ends up leaving home and becomes the keyboardist in a rave band
- While on stage, the protagonist wears a full suit that makes him look like a robot, thus hiding his robotic hands as part of the suit
- Near the end of the film, the protagonist sees his attackers (who were never caught) at a concert and points them out to his estranged father, who I think is a cop.

The replacement hands have a very mechanical look to them, similar to the prosthetics seen in Starship Troopers (below for reference), only more streamlined & gritty... more Borg-like. And the guy's full suit was made to match. Think Cyrax or Sektor from Mortal Kombat.

[image]

Comment: Were they hands of transcendental quickness?

Comment: @SJuan76 - It's more ironic that I spent longer looking up the Futurama quote then I did looking up the actual answer...

Comment: @Richard lol, too much time on your hands..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is "[Vibrations](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114845/)"

> *Rising rock star, TJ Cray, gets the shot of a lifetime, an audition with a A & R man. On the way into the city, a carload of drunks smash
>   into his car, severing his hands. He drops out of the business and
>   becomes a homeless drunk. Cray wakes up to a pulsing beat in an
>   abandoned warehouse, where a "rave" party is in full action. To his
>   rescue comes Anamika, a computer artist, who takes him outside for
>   fresh air. They become friends and eventually reinvent TJ's career.
>   With the help of friends, they replace his hands with prosthetics and
>   design a metallic cyber looking suit. TJ quickly becomes an overnight
>   sensation, known as Cyberstorm. The finale is a dramatic scenario
>   where TJ has to make crucial decisions about his new life.*

Comment: That indeed looks like the one. Ten minutes... how do you DO that?

Comment: @Omegacron - Well, it took me thirty seconds to identify it and another minute to type up the answer. Most of the delay was the fact that I wasn't looking at the front page but spotted it when it popped up in the chatroom feed.